# How to create txt file from runnable jar?

Tags: java, file, jar, executable-jar

In the following code, I first created a `File` in the root directory and then `write` string into it. Then I read data from that `File`:

```
        File file = new File("myfile.txt");
            if(!file.exists()){
                file.createNewFile();
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(com_port_hardcoded);
                bw.close();
            }
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(file);
            comPort = scn.nextLine().trim();
            scn.close();
```

Now, when I compile and run this code in eclipse, it works perfectly. But when I export a 'runnable jar' of this code, the `txt` file is not there in the folder of the jar.

I don't know where the `txt` file is generated or if it is generated at all.

Comment: Did you execute this jar: java -jar jar-file ?

Comment: Did you try to sysout file.getAbsoluteFile() into your console or a logfile?

Comment: are you sure your jar file is running ?

Comment: Have a look at [In Java, what is the default location for newly created files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154529/in-java-what-is-the-default-location-for-newly-created-files)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the generated file locate in the same jar folder, you can do this:

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "myfile.txt");
```