# what is the default keystore file name and location that java 8 keytool use?

Tags: windows, java-8, default, keystore, keytool

given the command 
c:\java\jre8\bin\keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048

as you can see I forgot to tell the file name and location
all went well and keystore seems to be created
BUT
where the keystore file was created?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

default filename will be **.keystore**

and location c:\Users\<CurrentUser>\.keystore

thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5154592/60114) that gave me a hint

Now that I know it it kind of makes sense.

additionally [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html):

> -keystore keystore
>   The keystore location.
>   ...
>   For example, if keytool -genkeypair is invoked and the
>   -keystore option is not specified, 
>  the default keystore file named **.keystore** in the **user's home directory** will be created if it does not
>   already exist. 
>   Similarly, if the -keystore ks_file option is specified
>   but ks_file does not exist, then it will be created